# Use body::selection, i want to customize highlight color

Tags: css, selection, textselection

Why cannot use `body::selection`, when i want anything that can highlight to be the color i desired, anything include p img li h1

Examples here
Now i want everything **highlight to be RED color**, but i am using `body::selection`, it never work

http://jsfiddle.net/kent93/nu6ju/

Comment: what is your question ? example works like a charm: `body::selection { background-color: red; }` does exactly what its supposed to do.

Comment: my question is why it does change img p li h1 highlight color into red color also?

Comment: because everything is nest inside body tag

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you want to apply the selection background to all elements, omit the type selector:

```
::selection {
    background: red;
}
```

And for that matter, add `::-moz-selection` so it works in Firefox too:

```
::-moz-selection {
    background: red;
}
::selection {
    background: red;
}
```

---

It was never decided how exactly the styles you set for `E::selection` for any element `E` should propagate to descendants of `E`. There's a much more in-depth discussion [in the www-style mailing list](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-style/2008Oct/0268.html). It is also for this reason that `::selection` has been totally dropped from CSS3 with the latest LC revision of CSS3 UI; see [this section](http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-css3-ui-20120117), which says:

> The ::selection pseudo-element has been dropped since it was dropped from Selectors after testing found interoperability problems and further details to explore/define.

My best guess is that browsers (at least Firefox) just don't apply the same rule to descendant elements. So if you apply the pseudo-element to `body`, then only `body` text will have the custom selection background; everything nested inside it won't have the selection background.

Comment: maybe you is right , cause i have tried a lot of way to make it, but no one make me feel happy

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stop cascading, you can add

`body *::selection { background: inherit; }`

So only text on the top level will be selected with red. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/nu6ju/4/